# Normalize unicode characters in C++ without ICU or boost?

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm trying to convert a string containing accents to a pure ASCII one in C++(for the purpose of indexing). I know this question has been asked countless times but unlike others I don't have the option to include any 3rd party library like ICU or even use boost.

So far I've tried creating a map of accented to normalized characters(unsigned char to unsigned char) like below

```
map<unsigned char, unsigned char> myMap;
myMap['ì'] = 'i'; //few more like this
```

and then this function

```
string result;
for(size_t i = 0; i < inputString.size(); i++) {
    if(myMap.count(inputString[i]) > 0) {
        result += myMap[inputString[i]];
    } else {
        result += inputString[i];
    }
}
```

but when I try it with a string like "Forlì", it return me `Forl<C3>i`. Why is that so? How can I remove this extra `<C3>` ?

Please note that this will be production level code so I will avoid including heavy classes for such a minor change(just the accented character case representable by unsigned char).

Comment: I would remind that both, ICU and Boost C++ libraries are free and open-source. Meaning that you can freely fetch sources anytime and look how they do it. This always works for me when I'm trying to "reinvent the wheel".

Comment: I actually tried including them, but ICU gave me junk(???) charcters instead of normalized values and there are always licensing issues. Furthermore ICU is not developer friendly and there is a lot of unnecessary conversion between string types for such a case

Comment: @rockstarjindal: If you're trying to stuff about 100K of Unicode characters in a `unsigned char`, then junk is to be expected. `'í'` might just work, but it's unlikely to be Unicode.

Comment: i've written only 25 such characters

Comment: @rockstarjindal My advice was to take a look to the source code (i.e. text) of major libraries for inspiration. It cannot lead to wrong results or to licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `unsigned short` for the first type of the map. Also save the source file in UTF16.

Ah.. with basic_string<char>, I don't think this code work anyhow.

Original text must be encoded with UTF8 or UTF16. Read it as ASCII will introduce C/C++ standard library character set conversion. I suspect C3 occurred in this step. This kind of coding handling could worsen the situation.

Unicode is just 65535 16 bit values, practically. If we aiming only alphabet like characters, proper code conversion is very doable, IMHO. But if we load it as ASCII, we must know how the C/C++ IO handles code conversion.

Compatibility, portability, ... very complicated. This is the one of the reason many people use ICU like libraries.